# Update Yii CListView using Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, yii

I'm working on Yii framework and I can't find my way out on filtering clistview results via ajax when for example I select country on dropdown list it should refine the query to  show results that matches the selected country. I have tried this tutorial https://kakousis.wordpress.com/2013/05/11/dropdown-ajax-based-filtering-of-clistview-in-yii/ but I'm still lost

probably you know any resource that might help me thanks.

Comment: what did you tried ? what error shows ?

Comment: Nothing display on the screen it's blank

Comment: share your code here